# For In loop with Filelist returns the wrong type

Tags: typescript, filelist

I'd like to loop through a FileList with a `for in` loop, using **Typescript**.
I started out with a regular old for loop, and this works perfectly:

```
let files:FileList = e.target.files
for(let i = 0;i<files.length;i++){
  doSomething(files[i])
}

function doSomething(f:File){
}
```

But when I use the shorter `for..in` loop:

```
for(let f in files){
   doSomething(f) 
}
```

I get an error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'`. So `f` is somehow deemed a string, even though a FileList contains Files, not strings.

These fixes don't work:

```
for(let f:File in files){ // left hand assignment not allowed
    doSomething(f as File) // cannot convert string to File
}
```

Is this just not possible?

Comment: should be `for (let f of files)` with `in` you will get the key, with `of` you will get the value. So `in` behaves like `Object.keys (obj).forEach( key => { ... } )` and `of` behaves like `Object.values (obj).forEach( value => { ... } )`

Comment: That's a good tip, but with `for of` I get: `Type FileList is not an array type or a string type`

Comment: What does the definiton of FileList look like?

Comment: It has almost nothing... : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList Apparently you can't use for of/for in with a FileList :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot iterate using

```
for(let f in files){
   doSomething(f) 
}
```

> A FileList is not an Array, but it does conform to its contract (has
>   length and numeric indices), so we can "borrow" Array methods:

you have to iterate as you are doing based on length.

You have to follow this syntax

```
for(let i = 0;i<files.length;i++){
  doSomething(files[i])
}
```

Refers to api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: Just a side question, is it possible to add a File to a FileList by code?